# How can I print out Core Data save error in Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

How can I print out Core Data save error in Swift?

As far as I have this two lines:

```
var error: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?> = nil
let success = managedObjectContext.save(error)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a pointer to an optional `NSError` object.
As an example, this is the template code from Xcode if you create an iOS app and select
the "Use Core Data" checkbox:

```
func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // ...
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
 func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch let nserror as NSError {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            print("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```